# Javascript snowfall horizontal scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a the snowfall on my website.

here is the
[Example][1]. It is working fine. The only issue I am getting is horizontal scroll which is causing because of canvas generated by the script. Also I want the snow shall fall till bottom. It will fall till bottom but once you will scroll the page the snowfall will stop till the screen height. i.e. 995px. I want the snow shall fall even i scroll the page to bottom.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gkat16t5/
```

Comment: So, you want the snow to always be falling on the page, no matter if you are scrolled down the page?

Comment: Correct, I want the show to fall even i scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you want it to show when you scroll down, do it like this:
First, add a class to the element:

```
function init() {
                container = document.createElement('div');
                container.classList.add("snow");
                //...
}
```

Then style it:

```
.snow{
    position:fixed; /*Positions it so it stays when you scroll down*/
    top:0; /*Makes it full screen*/
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    pointer-events:none; /*Allows the user to click through it*/
}
```

All done :D

### [JSFiddle Demo - With overflow](https://jsfiddle.net/ww5dag9b/)

### [JSFiddle Demo - Without overflow](https://jsfiddle.net/3qhjjbr8/)

Comment: You are sooooooooo good :) .. Thanks you so much Jacob. It works.

Comment: @RohitMehra no problem :D just note, `pointer-events` doesn't have the best support in IE, so I would not show the snow in IE > 11, or else the users will not be able to interact with the page.